# How to get column name dynamically in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have an excel sheet where users maintain data format month wise.
every new month the add a column with some prefix and maintain the format.
like for this month they will add the column name "OCT_Data_Format".
Please see the below screenshot.

[image]

Again in December they'll add a new column with new name "DEC_data_format".

I want to add a custom column with name "DataFormat"  and use the value of new column in every month.

Requesting you to please let me know if there is any function available in power bi to concatenate the  month name with prefix "_data_format".

like we do in programming. ex. [function.getcurrentmonthname + "_data_format"].value

Comment: I think, you can use DAX function to solve this.

Comment: @ProtapGhosh the same i want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating the name of the column based by current month "name" (it's not the full name to be precise) can be made like this (in DAX):

```
SWITCH (
    MONTH ( TODAY() ),
    1, "Jan",
    2, "Feb",
    3, "Mar",
    4, "Apr",
    5, "May",
    6, "Jun",
    7, "Jul",
    8, "Aug",
    9, "Sep",
    10, "Oct",
    11, "Nov",
    12, "Dec"
) & "_Data_Format"
```

But what you need is to [unpivot](https://radacad.com/pivot-and-unpivot-with-power-bi) your table and get all months data into two columns - `Attribute` and `Value`, where the values in attribute will be the names of the old columns and you can use standard filtering to find what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi @Andrey Nikolov , The column name was successfully concatenated but it is returning the column name in values too. i want to retrieve the column value by concatenating the column name. 

Please see the result . https://ibb.co/dbYm6Hd

Comment: @ShahabHaidar That's why I told you to unpivot the table.

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem:

```
CONCATENATE( SWITCH( [MONTH(NOW())], 1, "JAN", 2, "FEB", 3, "MAR", 4, "APR"  
               , 5, "MAY", 6, "JUN", 7, "JUL", 8, "AUG"  
               , 9, "SEP", 10, "OCT", 11, "NOV", 12, "DEC"  
               , "Unknown month number" ), "_data_format" )
```

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/concatenate-function-dax
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/month-function-dax
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/switch-function-dax

Comment: Hi @Protap Ghosh , The column name was successfully concatenated but it is returning the column name in values too. i want to retrieve the column value by concatenating the column name. 

Please see the result . https://ibb.co/dbYm6Hd